# Why does my window reset after everytime I call SDL_RenderPresent()?

Tags: rendering, viewport, sdl-2

I was trying to implement viewport. The thing I was doing is that I render in one viewport, than I call SDL_RenderPresent to update screen and then again I implemented viewport. The whole process was being controlled by key pressing, meaning by tapping c it used to render first viewport and then next one.  But calling SDL_RenderPresent after everytime rendering viewport was clearing up screen. Why is this happening? And can someone tell me that if SDL_Renderer works like a pen/brush with what we can draw things? If not, then how does it work?

Comment: You're supposed to redraw everything every frame. This is normal behavior.

Comment: And how does rendering work ? Like a pen/painting brush ? There's no relative answer in web

Comment: I have no idea what is "like a pen" here. Each frame you clear everything and issue drawing commands. There is no depth buffer so each draw will happen on top of previous ones. When frame is finished you present it to the screen and, if applicable, start drawing next frame.